# Stripe invoice.upcoming webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I want to know what is the example data from invoice.upcoming webhook of stripe.

Is the **data.object.id** is null?

Where I can get the amount? Is it on the **data.object.amount_paid** or **data.object.amount_due**?

And what is the **status** of this invoice?

Example data I got here in stackoverflow but I think it's not complete?

```
{
"created": 1326853478,
"livemode": false,
"id": "evt_000000000010000",
"type": "invoice.upcoming",
"object": "event",
"request": null,
"pending_webhooks": 1,
"api_version": "2017-06-05",
"data": {
  "object": {
    "id": null,
    "object": "invoice",
    "amount_due": 0,
    "amount_paid": 0,
    "application_fee": null,
    "attempt_count": 0,
    "attempted": true,
    "charge": null,
    "closed": true,
    "currency": "usd",
    "customer": "cus_J1QXR23OrUTxx1fk",
    "date": 1503541536,
    "description": null,
    "discount": null,
    "ending_balance": 0,
    "forgiven": false,
    "lines": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "sub_BNx15yNiTkAlQOye",
          "object": "line_item",
          "amount": 500,
          "currency": "jpy",
          "description": null,
          "discountable": true,
          "livemode": true,
          "metadata": {
          },
          "period": {
            "start": 1507604796,
            "end": 1510283196
          },
          "plan": {
            "id": "bplan",
            "object": "plan",
            "amount": 500,
            "created": 1504352393,
            "currency": "jpy",
            "interval": "month",
            "interval_count": 1,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "name": "B plan",
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "trial_period_days": null
          },
          "proration": false,
          "quantity": 1,
          "subscription": null,
          "subscription_item": "si_1B0LmKE9P3qCpf5erqbpMxkI",
          "type": "subscription"
        }
      ],
      "total_count": 1,
      "object": "list",
      "url": "/v1/invoices/in_1AuB2KE9P3qCpf5ekFh7qpAi/lines"
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "next_payment_attempt": null,
    "paid": true,
    "period_end": 1503541536,
    "period_start": 1503541536,
    "receipt_number": null,
    "starting_balance": 0,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "subscription": "sub2JQx1xlg9zIFhk",
    "subtotal": 0,
    "tax": null,
    "tax_percent": null,
    "total": 0,
    "webhooks_delivered_at": 1503541537
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Events generated from the Dashboard are totally fake, so I don't think you'll ever find usable data in them, but `amount_due` is what you want here.

Since Upcoming Invoices haven't been created yet - they're just a preview of future charges - they have no ID or status.

Comment: Is the *data.object.lines* is also empty here?

Comment: @bossajie using stripe's [test clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks) feature, I can tell you that `data.object.lines` is available in the `invoice.upcoming` event object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example of Stripe's `invoice.upcoming` event.
I found it using the [test clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks) feature. Please note that is the kind of data you'll get by renewing a yearly susbscription.

```json
{
  "object": "invoice",
  "account_country": "US",
  "account_name": "Your company",
  "account_tax_ids": null,
  "amount_due": 9900,
  "amount_paid": 0,
  "amount_remaining": 9900,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "attempt_count": 0,
  "attempted": false,
  "automatic_tax": {
    "enabled": false,
    "status": null
  },
  "billing_reason": "upcoming",
  "charge": null,
  "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
  "created": 1679397051,
  "currency": "usd",
  "custom_fields": null,
  "customer": "cus_XXXXXXXX",
  "customer_address": null,
  "customer_email": "xxxx@user.io",
  "customer_name": "Customer name",
  "customer_phone": null,
  "customer_shipping": null,
  "customer_tax_exempt": "none",
  "customer_tax_ids": [],
  "default_payment_method": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "default_tax_rates": [],
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "discounts": [],
  "due_date": null,
  "ending_balance": 0,
  "footer": null,
  "last_finalization_error": null,
  "lines": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "il_tmp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "object": "line_item",
        "amount": 9900,
        "currency": "usd",
        "description": "1 × Your sub (at $99.00 / year)",
        "discount_amounts": [],
        "discountable": true,
        "discounts": [],
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {},
        "period": {
          "end": 1711019451,
          "start": 1679397051
        },
        "plan": {
          "id": "price_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "object": "plan",
          "active": true,
          "aggregate_usage": null,
          "amount": 9900,
          "amount_decimal": "9900",
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1600678675,
          "currency": "usd",
          "interval": "year",
          "interval_count": 1,
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": null,
          "product": "prod_XXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_usage": null,
          "trial_period_days": null,
          "usage_type": "licensed"
        },
        "price": {
          "id": "price_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "object": "price",
          "active": true,
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1600678675,
          "currency": "usd",
          "livemode": false,
          "lookup_key": null,
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": null,
          "product": "prod_XXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "recurring": {
            "aggregate_usage": null,
            "interval": "year",
            "interval_count": 1,
            "trial_period_days": null,
            "usage_type": "licensed"
          },
          "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_quantity": null,
          "type": "recurring",
          "unit_amount": 9900,
          "unit_amount_decimal": "9900"
        },
        "proration": false,
        "proration_details": {
          "credited_items": null
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "subscription": "sub_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "subscription_item": "si_XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "tax_amounts": [],
        "tax_rates": [],
        "type": "subscription"
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/invoices/upcoming/lines?customer=cus_XXXXXXXXXXXX&subscription=sub_XXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_payment_attempt": 1679400651,
  "number": null,
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "paid": false,
  "paid_out_of_band": false,
  "payment_intent": null,
  "payment_settings": {
    "payment_method_options": null,
    "payment_method_types": null
  },
  "period_end": 1679397051,
  "period_start": 1647861051,
  "post_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
  "pre_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
  "quote": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "starting_balance": 0,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "status": "draft",
  "status_transitions": {
    "finalized_at": null,
    "marked_uncollectible_at": null,
    "paid_at": null,
    "voided_at": null
  },
  "subscription": "sub_XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "subtotal": 9900,
  "tax": null,
  "test_clock": "clock_1Kfj8pAP8XE2C2mat1YQW7Rg",
  "total": 9900,
  "total_discount_amounts": [],
  "total_tax_amounts": [],
  "transfer_data": null,
  "webhooks_delivered_at": null
}
```